# Book about interdimensional travel by use of a hallway

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe

I vaguely remember details about the book. I remember that travel between dimensions was regulated by either a company or government entity, and they used a box shaped hallway, basically a tesseract that had stretched infinitely in many directions forming a type of hallway with windows that could peer into those dimensions. Using controls, they could then enter those dimensions. One part talked about a "vacation world" where one of the characters had set up a house with a bunch of primitive life forms that inhabited it. I don't remember too much more as I never finished the book due to its size and time constraints at the time, although I am wanting to find it and start reading it again.

I believe that the town where they housed the interdimensional gateway at was in a mountain region, but it's been quite some time since I read the book. I do remember them briefly mentioning that Sherlock Holmes was real in one of the realities when describing some of the aspects of the multiverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know some of this reminds me of the [G.O.D Inc](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1380394.The_Labyrinth_of_Dreams) series by Jack L. Chalker.

This is a 3 book series consisting of

The Labyrinth of Dreams
The Shadow Dancers
The Maze in the Mirror

It has been a long time since I read these (about 25 years), but the titular G.O.D Inc has access to multiple Earths which I seem to recall were accessed from a hallway.

G.O.D Inc was located in McInerney, Oregon USA - which could match your recollection of a mountain region.

The protagonists are a husband and wife PI duo so while I don't remember Sherlock Holmes being part of the plot, it is possible.

Comment: I forgot about this post shortly after i posted it, but after being reminded i checked on them and the book i was looking for was actually the last in that series The Maze in the Mirror which is probably why i didn't finish reading it because i noticed i was reading the last part without reading the first parts , the part i was remembering about the mountains after reading it again realized what it was Describing PennStateUniversity,   "and it sits in Happy
Valley surrounded by stark mountains and a northern climate, often nearly
unreachable in mid-winter" that paragraph was what i remember